# Xamarin - How do I get my application to show up in the Open in... menu of "Photos"?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to add my app to iOS share menu (like instagram, facebook etc), and open selected items in my app. I develop xamarin forms app and I can do it on Xamarin Android. For iOS, I follow this documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html

And I follow this article:
https://codemilltech.com/sending-files-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-part-1-ios/

And I can do it in ios. But it only work for "Files". I also want to do this in the "Photos". My first question: How can I do this on photos?

And I receive responses with OpenUrl. If user makes multiple select and after they select share with xamarin app, how to receive responses? Because OpenUrl gets only one file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "It works only on Files" --> Do you mean the Files app?

Comment: I want to say "Files" directory. For example: When I want to share a file called "a.jpg" that is location "Files/Browse/On My iPhone/AppName/a.jpg", I can do. But when I try to share a picture in the "Photos", I can't see my app on share list.

Comment: If you want to let your app display on the menu when select the picture in system album . Add the following code to info.plist like `<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.item</string>
                <string>public.content</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>`  For more details  you could check https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Photos.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH17-SW1

Comment: Yes, I already did CFBundleDocumentTypes operation on info.plist But it didn't run on Photos. And I looked this link but is it convenient for me? because I don't want photo edit. I want to pass files to my app with open in (so share my app)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions

Comment: Yes, this is solution for me. But I have some trouble when I implement this for my xamarin forms app. I tried this documentation steps but I didn't do. Could you help me please? I asked with detail there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093390/how-to-implement-share-extension-to-xamarin-forms-ios-project

Comment: You could check Jack's answer , I think it will be a solution .

Comment: i have the same problem. where is the Jack's answer?

Comment: In this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093390/how-to-implement-share-extension-to-xamarin-forms-ios-project