# How to implement Share Extension to Xamarin.Forms - iOS project?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement a share extension to my `Xamarin.Forms` app. And I followed these:

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios8-share/

https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios8/Share

And git repo above works when I run it. But I need to implement this for my xamarin forms project.
So I did this steps:

1. I right clicked to my xamarin forms solution. After I select add, new project. And I created "Share Extension (iOS)" project. (I choosed .Net Framework 4.7.2)
2. A Share extension project is created with ShareViewController. I didn't do any change this.
3. I opened info.plist of new created ShareExtension project. And I paid attention bundle identifier. For example my xamarin project's bundle identifier is "com.xamarin.test" and my share extension project's bundle identifier is "com.xamarin.test.share-extension"
4. I selected MinimumOSVersion 10.0 of my main project and my share extension.
5. In my project,NSExtension is following:

   > NSExtension
   >
   > NSExtensionAttributes
   >
   > NSExtensionActivationRule
   >
   > NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount
   > 1
   > NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount
   > 1
   > NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount
   > 1
   > NSExtensionActivationSupportsText
   >
   > NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount
   > 1
   >
   >
   > NSExtensionMainStoryboard
   > MainInterface
   > NSExtensionPointIdentifier
   > com.apple.share-services
6. After I cleaned whole solution and rebuilt it, I added to reference shared extension project's DLL to my Xamarin iOS project. After that I run the project (on iPhone 7 iOS 12.0 simulator).

When I open photos and I click share for a photo, I expect to see my app on share menu. But it doesn't work. I guess I missed a step but what is this, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

> After I cleaned whole solution and rebuilded, I added to reference
>   shared extension project's dll to my xamarin ios project.

In the document, when it says about [Container app project requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions#container-app-project-requirements):

**It must maintain a reference to the Extension project.**

You should right click the `xamarin ios project` --> `Add a reference` --> `Choose the shared extension project`. What you are doing is a opposite way.

So remove the wrong reference and add the new reference, clean and rebuild your solution, run again.

Update:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand you said. I already do that. Firstly if I don't do "clean and rebuild", I can't see any file for add extension my ios project. I am adding a example project and video about what do I do. Where do I wrong? Could you help me please. I'm stuck here. Example video and app link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z8wpGmxkxI6Q97CA2Yqa8cHlQDTYyYZJ

Comment: And do I need to do any process on the apple developer side? Because I saw this link: https://medium.com/@timefrancesco/develop-and-deploy-ios8-extensions-with-xamarin-walkthrough-1b059a03e861 He said "Create an App Group and provisioning Profiles" etc. I also did these steps. But it doesn't run.

Comment: @PelinAlp I mean in your xamarin ios project, you should add a reference to your extension project instead of add a reference to xamarin ios project in your extension project. See my updated screenshot.

Comment: Also remember to clean and rebuild after adding the reference.

Comment: As you can see in video, I already did as your said. Video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_cGKFy9lrZtvz418z5eg3FvwdLWTwy60

Comment: @PelinAlp  right click the xamarin ios project --> Add a reference --> Choose `Project` not `Assemblies` --> extension project -->ok. Remember to remove the old reference in your extension project.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I can understand now. I always work to add the extension again. But it was already there. And I asked lots of question, thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0):

Can Deployment Targets be different?I added Share extension it worked directly. Info.plist also looks correct.
Is Deployment Target iOS 12+?

Edit: First answer is another question's answer. Let's think as if it didn't never exist :)

Comment: I tried this. But it still doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

As [stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions#extension-project-requirements), you want to make sure all the project references are correct. Another important thing when testing on a device, make sure you do so in release configuration with the linker on, as it is [clarified here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions#debug-and-release-versions-of-extensions).

And finally, if you want to use your Xamarin.Forms UI (Xaml pages) in your extension, follow this [recently published walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions-with-xamarinforms).