# Sharing image via my app in xamarin.forms iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I can click on any image or file stored under My Files and am able to see my Xamarin form app while clicking the share button.

I am not able to do the same when clicking any photos present in the gallery on iOS.

Are any specific settings required for this?

Below is my info.plist file configuration

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos gallery for picking photos and videos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery for picking photos and videos.</string>



<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>Image</string>
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
<array>
<string>public.image</string>
</array>
</dict>

</array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, the image uses UIActivityViewController to share items. UIActivityViewController allows app users to easily share data between the current app and services. You can check the usage of [UIActivityViewController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiactivityviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12).

For how to use xamarin.ios code in xamarin.forms applications, you can refer to the [DependencyService documentation in Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/registration-and-resolution).

**UpDate:** [Extensions in Xamarin iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/extensions) can help you, and you can refer to the thread for using it in Forms: [How to implement Share Extension to Xamarin.Forms - iOS project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093390/how-to-implement-share-extension-to-xamarin-forms-ios-project)

Comment: thanks for the reply. My question is I don't see my app when I share any image from "Photos" in iOS xamarin form. I can see my app if I share it from MyFiles but not from Gallery.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can try it.